# How can I add an Upload File field to a Wagtail Form?

Tags: django, forms, wagtail

I want to make File Upload a possible Wagtail Form field type on form pages. How do I configure the models to make this possible? Please note I am more interested in allowing users to upload document files like PDFs rather than images.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a [great article](https://posts-by.lb.ee/image-uploads-in-wagtail-forms-3121c9b35d27) from LB Johnson on that matter. The code below is directly taken from the article (but copying here in case the article goes away), however you might want to follow the article as it explains everything step by step.

It's quite involved at the moment, you'll need to:

1. extend `AbstractFormField` to define a new field type.
2. extend `FormBuilder` to deal with the new field type.
3. set `form_builder` to your custom `FormBuilder` class on your FormPage .
4. override the `serve` method on the FormPage to pass the file data to the form (only if you use Wagtail 1.12 and below as it does it automatically from [Wagtail 1.13](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/commit/0b90ee15faedb35df5f180becb1e78681f919a62))
5. override the `process_form_submission` to process the file

Here is the full code:

```
from wagtail.wagtailforms.models import AbstractFormField, FORM_FIELD_CHOICES
from wagtail.wagtailforms.forms import FormBuilder
from wagtail.wagtailimages.fields import WagtailImageField


def filename_to_title(filename):
    from os.path import splitext
    if filename:
        result = splitext(filename)[0]
        result = result.replace('-', ' ').replace('_', ' ')
        return result.title()


class FormField(AbstractFormField):
    FORM_FIELD_CHOICES = list(FORM_FIELD_CHOICES) + [('image', 'Upload Image')]
    field_type = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('field type'),
        max_length=16,
        choices=FORM_FIELD_CHOICES)
    page = ParentalKey('FormPage', related_name='form_fields')


class ExtendedFormBuilder(FormBuilder):
    def create_image_upload_field(self, field, options):
        return WagtailImageField(**options)
    FIELD_TYPES = FormBuilder.FIELD_TYPES
    FIELD_TYPES.update({
        'image': create_image_upload_field,
    })


class FormPage(AbstractEmailForm):
    form_builder = ExtendedFormBuilder

    def serve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            # form = self.get_form(request.POST, page=self, user=request.user)  # Original line
            form = self.get_form(request.POST, request.FILES, page=self, user=request.user)

            if form.is_valid():
                self.process_form_submission(form)
                return render(
                    request,
                    self.get_landing_page_template(request),
                    self.get_context(request)
                )
        else:
            form = self.get_form(page=self, user=request.user)

        context = self.get_context(request)
        context['form'] = form
        return render(
            request,
            self.get_template(request),
            context
        )

    def process_form_submission(self, form):
        cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data

        for name, field in form.fields.iteritems():
            if isinstance(field, WagtailImageField):
                image_file_data = cleaned_data[name]
                if image_file_data:
                    ImageModel = get_image_model()
                    image = ImageModel(
                        file=cleaned_data[name],
                        title=filename_to_title(cleaned_data[name].name),
                        collection=self.upload_image_to_collection,
                        # assumes there is always a user - will fail otherwise
                        uploaded_by_user=form.user,
                        )
                    image.save()
                    cleaned_data.update({name: image.id})
                else:
                    # remove the value from the data
                    del cleaned_data[name]

        form_data = json.dumps(cleaned_data, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
        submission_object = dict(
            page=self,
            form_data=form_data,
            user=form.user,
        )

    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)
    thank_you_text = RichTextField(blank=True)

    FormPage.content_panels = [
        FieldPanel('title', classname="full title"),
        FieldPanel('intro', classname="full"),
        InlinePanel('form_fields', label="Form fields"),
        FieldPanel('thank_you_text', classname="full"),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldRowPanel([
                FieldPanel('from_address', classname="col6"),
                FieldPanel('to_address', classname="col6"),
            ]),
            FieldPanel('subject'),
        ], "Email"),
]
```

Here is the (untested) code to handle a document instead of an image:

```
from django.forms import FileField
from wagtail.wagtaildocs.models import get_document_model
# Other imports

class FormField(AbstractFormField):
    FORM_FIELD_CHOICES = list(FORM_FIELD_CHOICES) + [('document', 'Upload Document')]
    # `field_type` and `page` remain unchanged


class ExtendedFormBuilder(FormBuilder):
    def create_document_upload_field(self, field, options):
        return FileField(**options)
    FIELD_TYPES = FormBuilder.FIELD_TYPES
    FIELD_TYPES.update({
        'document': create_document_upload_field,
    })

class FormPage(AbstractEmailForm):
    # `form_builder` attribute and `serve` remain unchanged.

    def process_form_submission(self, form):
        cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data

        for name, field in form.fields.iteritems():
            if isinstance(field, FileField):
                document_file_data = cleaned_data[name]
                if document_file_data:
                    DocumentModel = get_document_model()
                    document = DocumentModel(
                        file=cleaned_data[name],
                        title=filename_to_title(cleaned_data[name].name),
                        # assumes there is always a user - will fail otherwise
                        uploaded_by_user=form.user,
                    )
                    document.save()
                    cleaned_data.update({name: document.id})
                else:
                    # remove the value from the data
                    del cleaned_data[name]

        # The rest of the function is unchanged
```

Comment: thank you! But what if I wanted to allow users to upload a PDF, so a document instead of an image?

Comment: Sorry I missed the part of the question where you ask for document instead of image. That being said, the steps are identical and I really encourage you to try to tweak the code above yourself and understand how it all works together. I've added an example if you get stuck, although I did not have time to test it.

Comment: Cannot have FIELD_TYPES object in FormBuilder how can i solve this. Can you give me code for this. @LoïcTeixeira

Comment: Hey, I have recently revised the original post about adding image uploads and it works on Wagtail 2.10 - https://dev.to/lb/image-uploads-in-wagtail-forms-39pl I hope this helps anyone getting to this question in > 2020.

Answer (score 3):

Now there are some changes made by wagtail developer in FormBuilder So in Below given code is not working now

```
class ExtendedFormBuilder(FormBuilder):
def create_document_upload_field(self, field, options):
    return FileField(**options)
FIELD_TYPES = FormBuilder.FIELD_TYPES
FIELD_TYPES.update({
    'document': create_document_upload_field,
})
```

Instead of this they made

```
class ExtendedFormBuilder(FormBuilder):
    def create_document_upload_field(self, field, options):
        return FileField(**options)
    FIELD_TYPES = FormBuilder.formfields
```

Wagtail Core developer changed FormBuilder.FIELD_TYPES property to FormBuilder.formfields

So i hope this is helpful for developer to let you know which changes happened recently.

Comment: Hey, I have recently updated my original post (referenced in the question above) and it works on Wagtail 2.10 - https://dev.to/lb/image-uploads-in-wagtail-forms-39pl