# How can I integrate a file upload field in Wagtail 2 Form Builder?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I want to add a new form field to the Wagtail Form Builder to create a file upload field. There's a related question with an accepted answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47932918/2074077 but that's for an older version of Wagtail.

How can I add a File Upload Field to the Wagtail 2 (or newer) Form Builder?

This is the code I have but I'm not sure where to integrate a File Upload field as an option.

```
 from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
 from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import (
     FieldPanel, FieldRowPanel,
     InlinePanel, MultiFieldPanel
 )
 from wagtail.core.fields import RichTextField
 from wagtail.contrib.forms.models import AbstractEmailForm, 
 AbstractFormField


 class FormField(AbstractFormField):
     page = ParentalKey('FormPage', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
     related_name='custom_form_fields')


 class FormPage(AbstractEmailForm):

    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)
    thank_you_text = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = AbstractEmailForm.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('intro', classname="full"),
        InlinePanel('custom_form_fields', label="Form fields"),
        FieldPanel('thank_you_text', classname="full"),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldRowPanel([
                FieldPanel('from_address', classname="col6"),
                FieldPanel('to_address', classname="col6"),
            ]),
            FieldPanel('subject'),
        ], "Email"),
    ]

    def get_form_fields(self):
        return self.custom_form_fields.all()
```

Comment: The question should state Wagtail 2.0 or newer. The accepted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47932918/2074077 is for an older version of Wagtail (up to version 1.13). Wagtail 2 uses different paths and there are likely a couple small form tweaks.

Comment: I have implemented already and its working fine but i want process_form method code as he mentioned in that question can you send me plz...@KalobTaulien